# How can I use anchor links in Angular 6 without them refreshing the page?

Tags: angular, html

I'm creating a simple website that's has two different looking pages, on one are 5 items in navigation in second are 3. In home component, that is my main route outlet I have 2 links:

```
<a href="#section1">Some link</a>
```

When i click on it, it moves me to `<section id="section1"></section>`

App.component:

```
<navigation></navigation>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer></footer>
```

When I am on second route `/someLink` i have different navigation to that page and I want to click on link `<a href="#otherSection">Some other link</a>` and moves to `section` in currently opened page in `/someLink`.

When i click on this link it moves me to `home component` and refresh the page.

Am I doing this wrong or this is just impossible to do ?

Comment: instead of href, use routerLink to navigate

Comment: routerLink needs configured route for this, instead of href your sugestion moves me to /section not to /#section (it works bad and refresh the page)

Comment: do you have /section route? or is that id of element?

Comment: This is id of element